# Can't boot ubuntu 14.04 on virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, login

I have been using Ubuntu on Windows 7 through an Oracle VM VirtualBox. A few days ago, my password started to be asked in order to login on graphical mode (before, my password was never asked and I have not changed any settings).
After entering my password, the screen goes black and I get to the login screen again. I have changed my password, but it has not solved the problem.
I have tried to login in guest session mode, but it does not work either. I have the impression the desktop manager does not work. If I go into terminal mode, it works.
I am using lightgdm. Today I installed gdm but it does not work either. I have also changed the privileges on .Xauthority, unsuccessfully.
Today I realized that the problem started happening after a Windows 7 update, but I do not know if this has an influence or not.
Any help to try to solve this would be appreciated.

Messages in .xsession-error include

init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning

init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2067) terminated with status 1

init: unity-settings-daemon main process (2057) killed by TERM signal

init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus

init: logrotate main process (1959) killed by TERM signal

init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash) main process (1998) killed by TERM signal

init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_ibus_ibus-ui_gtk3.1000.crash) main process (1999) killed by TERM signal

init: xsession-init main process (2054) killed by TERM signal

init: hud main process (2064) killed by TERM signal

init: unity-panel-service main process (2096) killed by TERM signal

Thanks,

Laura

Answer (score 0):

Go to your tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).  Then login with your username and password as they are now.

Then type the following:

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority_2016-06-16
sudo service lightgdm restart
```

and type in your password.

If this still doesn't work, you could

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/
```

...replacing `user` with your username.

**Explanation:**

The first command deletes the .Xauthority file, which will be recreated.  It is not infrequent for the .Xauthority to get the permissions messed up, and consequently it will refuse to allow you to log in.  The command with lightgdm is just restarting the window manager.

The second command attempts to change any files in your home directory that belong to a different user to your own user.